# Binary tree not inserting to right of any node that is the left child of another node

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

My current insert method for my binary tree is not inserting to the right of any node that is the left child of its parent.
current code:

```
private BinaryTreeNode insert(BinaryTreeNode current, String word) {
    if (current == null) {
        current = new BinaryTreeNode(word);
    } else {
        if (word.compareToIgnoreCase(current.value) < 0) { // if smaller than current node
            if (current.left != null) {
                if (word.compareToIgnoreCase(current.left.value) < 0) {// check next node for lesser than,
                    current.left = (insert(current.left, word));
                }
            } else {
                current.left = new BinaryTreeNode(word);// iff current node is end of tree
                System.out.println(word + "left");
            }
        } else {
            if (current.right != null) { // if larger than current node
                current.right = (insert(current.right, word));
            } else {
                current.right = new BinaryTreeNode(word); // if current node is end of tree
                System.out.println(word + "right");
            }
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
if (word.compareToIgnoreCase(current.left.value) < 0) {// check next node for lesser than,
    current.left = (insert(current.left, word));
}
```

What are you expecting this to do? You already know you should be inserting to the left of the current node, but why are you re-checking the next node down here?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I am not sure as to why I had that line in there. I have removed it, Waiting now for the test case to finish running.

Answer (score 0):

You should recurse instead of reaching down to compare to the left:

```
private static BinaryTreeNode insert(BinaryTreeNode current, String word) {
    if (current == null) {
        current = new BinaryTreeNode(word);
    } else {
        int test = word.compareToIgnoreCase(current.value);
        if (test < 0) {
            current.left = insert(current.left, word);
        } else if (test > 0) {
            current.right = insert(current.right, word);
        }
        // else word already at this node!
    }
    return current;
}
```

Note that the function should be static, since it doesn't depend on `this`.

Comment: (To be picky: The OP should "employ recursion", and the `insert` method should "recur".  I'm guessing that the OP has done enough cursing on this project already that he doesn't need to "recurse".)

Answer (score 0):

I think there were some errors... I would do something like this:

```
private void insert(BinaryTreeNode current, String word) {
    if (current == null) {
        current = new BinaryTreeNode(word);
    } else {
        if (word.compareToIgnoreCase(current.value) < 0) {

            if (current.left != null) {
                insert(current.left, word);
            } else {
                current.left = new BinaryTreeNode(word);
                System.out.println(word + "left");
            }

        } else {

            if (current.right != null) {
                insert(current.right, word);
            } else {
                current.right = new BinaryTreeNode(word); 
                System.out.println(word + "right");
            }

        }
    }
}
```